# Granger causality test interpretation

Tags: python, statsmodels, var, p-value, causality

When I ran the below code for my dataset I got the following results. I do not know how to eliminate few features based on the outcome

Code:

```
maxlag=12
test = 'ssr_chi2test'
def grangers_causation_matrix(data, variables, test='ssr_chi2test', verbose=False):  
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(variables), len(variables))), columns=variables, index=variables)
    for c in df.columns:
        for r in df.index:
            test_result = grangercausalitytests(data[[r, c]], maxlag=maxlag, verbose=False)
            p_values = [round(test_result[i+1][0][test][1],4) for i in range(maxlag)]
            if verbose: print(f'Y = {r}, X = {c}, P Values = {p_values}')
            min_p_value = np.min(p_values)
            df.loc[r, c] = min_p_value
    df.columns = [var + '_x' for var in variables]
    df.index = [var + '_y' for var in variables]
    return df

grangers_causation_matrix(df, variables = df.columns)
```

output:

[image: Output of Granger causality test]

The above results in the image show that AOV_x causes all other variables except for Revenue_y and ARPC_y (since p>0.05). Now I am not able to decide if i should drop AOV_x or not as it causes some and not others.

I am expecting to understand how to proceed if Granger causality test results in p values >0.05

Comment: Please remember that Stack Overflow is not your favourite Python forum, but rather a question and answer site for all programming related questions. Thus, please always include the tag of the language you are programming in, that way other users familiar with that language can more easily find your question. Take the [tour] and read up on [ask] to get more information on how this site works, then [edit] the question with the relevant tags.

Comment: This appears to be more of a question about statistics, i.e. interpretation and modification of the Granger test, rather than about programming per se. In that case, Stack Overflow is not the right place to ask this, rather [stats.se] would be better.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Will try to get a solution on cross validated